# Is it worth to use redux on tables?

Tags: reactjs, redux, architecture, jsx, react-table

I'm trying to build an application which will be formed by several CRUD and several graphic tables (similar to excel and containing hundreds of rows) which will be editable by users.

I've already created a CRUD with react and redux, now I'm wondering if the tables should be implemented with redux as well or not.

Thinking about it a jsx row of a table is like an element of **CRUD**, in fact I need to be able to Create a new row, Read, Update and Delete it.
Is it correct to use **redux** (and so create all the logic needed, reducers actions ..)for **editable tables**? Is there a best practice or a standard approach for this case ?

Comment: Do you need the state to be global to the application?  Or local to a specific component?  Redux exists specifically for the former, so if that's not what you need then just manage the state in the component that owns it.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look on [Material Table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started). It has built-in feature for table editing.

About the connection Redux-Table, it totally up to you. If the data displayed in the table come from the store and you want to keep them there (to not call an api, if any, to get updated data) you should write all the redux stuff (reducer, actions...).

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! The data will come from files and then they will be sent to java backed and saved in database

Comment: So i think you can use redux then